# Developer options only show USB debugging on QMobile devices

Tags: developer-options

I have QMobile with Android 5.1 (rooted). I have enabled Developers option by tapping 7 times the option which enables it, and there are supposed to be a few options in the Developer options. However, there is only a single USB debugging setting.

> [image: Developer options with only USB debugging option shown]

I want to enable mock locations. The settings which are supposed to be there can be searched but cannot be enabled.

I have tried all the solutions: factory reset, upgraded the OS, tweaked, but nothing worked.

Comment: Even after Factory Reset the problem remains? Oh, and your storage is almost full, sometimes this can prevent a device from working normally

Comment: No , Its Not a problem I have cleared Storage . is there is any third party app or tweak?

Comment: Seems like a bug. If factory resetting didn't help, you should consider flashing the phone. Also, you should expect that  the constructors may have expressly removed the missing options.

Comment: i searched thru internet  for this problem all are , incomplete topics ,

Comment: Manufacturers can customize Android ROM and disable some developer options, so one of the solutions is to flash custom ROM (if possible).